# Interaction facet not saving to xDB

Tags: xdb, xconnect

Sitecore 9.1

I have a super simple interaction facet that I am trying to push into xDB. 
Below are the facet, the model, the Json representation that I put into the xConnect Models folder and the client API call.

It does not error as long as I have any kind of an event (my goal) in the interaction. It runs, but it does not save my facet. If I remove the goal/event, it errors since I believe the interaction is empty. Seems like the facet just isn't being added to the interaction before I call the client.

I have gone over this code several times. I just can't see what I am missing.

### The issue

When the code below runs, it runs successfully. But I only get the goal in the interaction. The facets are empty. No errors in the logs.

***Additional error message for question SEO***
The type of this instance does not correspond to any type in the model. The type is Client.XdbModels.Facets.SwimEvent.

### The facet

```
{
    using System;
    using Sitecore.XConnect;

    [FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
    [Serializable]
    public class SwimEvent : Facet
    {
        public SwimEvent()
        {
        }

        public const string DefaultFacetKey = "SwimEvent";

        public string PoolId { get; set; }

        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### The Model

```
{
    using Sitecore.XConnect;
    using Sitecore.XConnect.Schema;
    using Client.Integrations.Swim.Facets;

    public class SwimEventModel
    {
        public static XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();

        private static XdbModel BuildModel()
        {
            var modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("SwimEventModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));

            modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);

            modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Interaction, SwimEvent>(SwimEvent.DefaultFacetKey);

            return modelBuilder.BuildModel();

        }
    }
}
```

### The model representation

```
{
  "Name": "SwimEventModel",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "References": [
    {
      "Name": "XConnect",
      "Version": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model",
      "Version": "9.0"
    }
  ],
  "Types": {
    "Usms.Integrations.Swim.Facets.SwimEvent": {
      "Type": "Facet",
      "BaseType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Facet",
      "ClrType": "Client.Integrations.Swim.Facets.SwimEvent, Client.Integrations.Swim, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Properties": {
        "PoolId": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "EventDate": {
          "Type": "DateTime"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Facets": [
    {
      "Target": "Interaction",
      "Name": "SwimEvent",
      "Type": "Client.Integrations.Swim.Facets.SwimEvent"
    }
  ]
}
```

### The client call

```
public async Task AddEvent(string email)
{
    using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
    {
        {
            try
            {

                var existingContactTask = client.GetAsync<Sitecore.XConnect.Contact>(new IdentifiedContactReference(Sitecore.Foundation.Accounts.Constants.Strings.UserLoginIdentifier, "me@gmail.com"), new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions());

                var existingContact = await existingContactTask;

                if (existingContact != null)
                {
                    var channelId = Guid.Parse("7EAA9ED7-188F-40CA-80B9-4439C28386C9");  // Replace with real channel ID
                    var userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X)";

                    var interaction = new Interaction(existingContact, InteractionInitiator.Contact, channelId, userAgent);

                    var goalID = Guid.Parse("{CFE46AAF-7ECF-456F-8823-A27DF80BDB82}"); // ID of goal item
                    var goal = new Goal(goalID, DateTime.UtcNow) {EngagementValue = 20};
                    interaction.Events.Add(goal);

                    client.SetFacet<SwimEvent>(interaction, SwimEvent.DefaultFacetKey, new SwimEvent() { PoolId = "123" });

                    client.AddInteraction(interaction);

                    await client.SubmitAsync();
                    }
                }
            catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
            {
                // Handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might not be the issue but you need to deploy your json model to two folders in xconnect.

Comment: Yup. Xconnect models and indexer models folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot all about the model patch config to tell Sitecore about the model type. Once I patched in this config, I was back in action.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <xconnect>
            <runtime type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.RuntimeModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
                <schemas hint="list:AddModelConfiguration">
                    <!-- value of 'name' property must be unique -->
                    <schema name="swimevent" type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration" patch:after="schema[@name='collectionmodel']">
                        <param desc="modeltype">Client.Integrations.Swim.Models.SwimEventModel, Client.Integrations.Swim</param>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </runtime>
        </xconnect>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

When you are working outsid

```
{
    var collectionClient = new CollectionWebApiClient(new Uri(Constants.XConnectDomain.Url + "/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });

    var searchClient = new SearchWebApiClient(new Uri(Constants.XConnectDomain.Url + "/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });

    var configurationClient = new ConfigurationWebApiClient(new Uri(Constants.XConnectDomain.Url + "/configuration"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });

    // HERE IS WHERE YOU ADD YOUR MODEL
    XdbModel[] models = { CollectionModel.Model, SwimEventModel.Model };

    var config = new XConnectClientConfiguration(new XdbRuntimeModel(models), collectionClient, searchClient, configurationClient);
}
```